# How to make Cypress NOT wait between clicks

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress

I have a test case where we found a bug that surfaces when you rapidly click two buttons on the page. I'm trying to write a test around this, so I need to make Cypress rapidly click the two buttons rather than waiting for the first click event to complete. Is this even possible in Cypress? I am not finding any information that seems to be what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to `click()` with a combination of the arguments `multiple` (Serially click multiple elements) and `force` (Forces the action, disables waiting for actionability). [Documentation with details](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/click.html#Arguments).

Example:

```
cy.get(".my-button").click({ multiple: true, force: true});
```

Note that the selector `cy.get(".my-button")` must return *both* of your buttons.